# Physical Explanation of the steady state in RC circuits

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, equilibrium

Given a simple RC circuit with a resistance $R$ connected to a capacitor $C$, the differential equation that describes the voltage is $$C \dot V + V/R = 0$$ whose solution is $$V= V(t) = V_0 e^{-t/\tau}$$ where $\tau = RC$. Also, the time that corresponds to the steady (discharged) state is equal to $t_0 = 5 \tau$ after which the voltage is considered to be 0 Volts.
My question is the following:

Does the stabilization after $t_0$ have a physical meaning or it's just a mathematized concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. The time evolution stays the same: $V(t)=V_0 e^{-5}e^{-t/\tau}$, the "non stabilized" part of the total voltage is just smaller. Often this part is considered constant for practical purposes.

Comment: So, it depends on the problem, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, it does. Because the current (instant) voltage $V(t)$ can be "initial" for another problem.

Answer (score 1):

After $5 \tau$, the voltage across the capacitor is about $.7$% of what it was originally. There are definitely situations where this $.7$% could be significant, so when the problem says you can consider this voltage to be zero, it probably means that the accuracy of any tool you would use to measure the system is low enough that it wouldn't be able to detect the $.7$%, so the $.7$% looks just like $0$.